# My query won't work. Any ideas

Tags: hql

I am running a query on HQL but keep getting error messages.

```
Select *
From cdb_1234;
Where src_inst = '1' '2'
Group by acc
Having count (*) >1
```

The group by is a column in the dataset.
Please help
It says parseexception cannot recognise input

Comment: `src_inst = '1' '2'` ?

Comment: This query has more than one error. Whirl Mind has posted a solution. Please reply if is OK or not

Answer (score 0):

Your semicolon ; should come after the whole query is complete. 
Also, you can't say "Select *" if you are using a Group By clause. 
You should use an aggregation phrase like count(*). 
Also make sure src_inst is a string or text field, and not numeric. If it is a numeric field, you should use src_inst in (1, 2)

Guessing from the bad query, here is something probably you could try :

```
Select *
From cdb_1234 
Where src_inst In ('1' ,'2')
And acc in (select acc From cdb_1234 
Where src_inst In ('1' ,'2')
Group by acc
Having count (*) >1
)
```

Comment: Apologies for the bad query, I'm just learning and wanted to know where I was going wrong. Appreciate the responses

Comment: If any of the answers did work for you, please mark it as an answer, for the benefit of future readers. :-)

Comment: No I have just checked and it won't work. Back to the drawing board

Comment: Could you confirm whether the datatype of src_inst is numeric or is it a string ?